# Reading file in a pattern using awk

Tags: awk

I have an input file in following manner

```
<td> Name1 </td>
<td> <span class="test"><a href="url1">Link </a></span></td>
<td> Name2 </td>
<td> <span class="test"><a href="url2">Link </a></span></td>
```

I want a awk script to read this file and output in following manner

```
url1 Name1
url2 Name2
```

Can anyone help me out in this trivial looking problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Extracting one href per is relatively simple, so long as they conform to XHTML standards and there is only at most one on a line and you don't care about enclosing tags, but perl is easier:</s>

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /href="([^"]+)"/'
```

If you care about enclosing tags or they are not standard conformant, you cannot use regular expressions to parse HTML. It is impossible.

added: oops, you do care about context, forget about regexps and use a real HTML parser

Comment: Your easy perl script doesn't cut it ;-). With the given input it outputs the lines "url1" and "url2".

Comment: +1 for pointing out the need for a real parser (and using the term *plesiochronous*).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk script that does the job

```
awk '
/a href=\".*\"/ { sub( /^.*a href=\"/,"" ); sub(/\".*/,"");  print $0, name }
                { name = $2 }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work:

```
awk 'BEGIN
     {i=1}{line[i++]=$0}
     END
     {
      j=1; 
      while (j<i) 
      {print line[j+1] line[j]; j+=2}
     }' yourfile|awk '{print substr($4,7,length($4)-6),$6}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '/^<td>/ {n = $2; getline; print gensub(/.*href="([^"]*).*/,"\\1",1), n}' infile

url1 Name1
url2 Name2
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk 'BEGIN{RS="></td>\n"; FS="> | </|\""}{print $7, $2}' infile`

every 2 lines as a record.